# How to average values in one table based on the condition involving another table in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, average

I have two tables. One defines time intervals (beginning and end). Time intervals are not equal in length. Another contains product ID, start and end date of the product.

```
TableOne: 
Interval   StartDateTime             EndDateTime
202020201  2020-01-01 00:00:00       2020-02-10 00:00:00
202020202  2020-02-10 00:00:00       2020-02-20 00:00:00 

TableTwo
ProductID  ProductStartDateTime      ProductEndDateTime
ASSDWE1    2018-01-04  00:12:00      2020-04-10  20:00:30
ADFGHER    2020-01-05  00:11:30      2020-01-19  00:00:00
ASDFVBN    2017-10-10  00:12:10      2020-02-23  00:23:23
```

I need to compute the average length of the products from TableTwo that existed during time intervals defined in TableOne. If the product existed throughout the time interval from TableOne, then the length of the product during this time interval is defined as it length since its start date till the end of the time interval.

I tried the following

```
select 
a.*,
(select  
  AVG(datediff(day, b.ProductStartDateTime, IIF (b.ProductEndDateTime> a.EndDateTime, a.EndDateTime 
  ,b.ProductEndDateTime))) --compute average length of the products
  FROM #TableTwo b
   WHERE ( not (b.ProductEndDateTime <=  a.StartDateTime ) and not (b.ProductStartDateTime >=  a.EndDateTime) ) 
        -- select products that existed during interval from #TableOne
                     ) as AverageProductLength

from #TableOne a
```

I get the mistake `"Multiple columns are specified in an aggregated expression containing an outer reference. If an expression being aggregated contains an outer reference, then that outer reference must be the only column referenced in the expression."`

The result I want:

```
   Interval   StartDateTime             EndDateTime         AverageProductLength
    202020201  2020-01-01 00:00:00       2020-02-10 00:00:00    23 
    202020202  2020-02-10 00:00:00       2020-02-20 00:00:00    34.5
```

Is there a way I can do the averaging?

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Show the results you want.  An explanation based on actual data (in a tabular format!) is usually easier to follow.  In addition, your time frames are adjacent.  Is that really intended?

Comment: (1)-(2).Thank you. Edited.  Time frames are indeed adjacent, but not equal in length.